# What's better/faster? Try-catch or avoid exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I would like to know, what's better or/and faster in general programming? Avoid the exception or wait for the exception?

Avoid the exception would be:

```
string a = null;
list = someMethod();
if(list.Length > 0 ){
   a = list[0];
}
if(a!=null) ...
```

Or try catch exception...

```
string a = null;
try{
    a = someMethod()[0];
catch{}
if(a!=null) ...
```

Comment: Cancel the word "faster", it's irrelevant. And that's not even the right way to use try-catch since you're sort of trolling the CLR.

Comment: @BoltClock, no it's not.  If the exception happens.  It is slower.

Comment: @Chad: OK, fine, less relevant.

Comment: What's better? *Avoiding* a heart attack by eating right and exercising, or *deliberately causing a heart attack* and then having the quintuple bypass surgery to fix it up afterwards?  Always always always avoid exceptions if you can. **An exception that could have been avoided but wasn't is a bug.**

Comment: in fact, if it is really only 1 condition and able to escape, it is easy question, we will use if else. maybe asking properly so that you can bait a better answer. for example, if you can only check rather or not it throw by checking "a lot of things, and those things are computationally expensive",  or hard to be implemented, and the operations with try catch does valid to skip if it has error. in this case, should i use try catch

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Performance is not the most relevant concern here. The question is, which of the two leads to more readable/maintainable/testable programs. You can worry about performance later.

In general, don't use exceptions for flow control. They are effectively a non-local `goto` which makes programs more difficult to read and follow. As such, they should be reserved for exceptional situations. If you can get away with not using a `try-catch` block for flow control, don't. Your programs will be more readable and maintainable.

The "right" way to handle this situation is

```
var list = someMethod();
if(list == null || list.Length == 0) {
    // handle something bad
}
string a = list[0];
if(a != null) {
    // go
}
```

You can avoid the check that `list` is not null and not empty if there is a contract (`Contract.Ensures`) that guarantees the return value from `someMethod` is not null and not empty.

It is true, however, that exceptions are locally expensive. Whether or not they will impact the performance of your program (i.e., are a bottleneck) is another question altogether. But used properly, exceptions are generally not a bottleneck (who cares about performance when your application is crashing?)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer, I knew something was not right with a try and empty catch. About programs more maintainable is very true. Maybe another exception not expected can occur and you will never know. Maybe an empty catch would make sense if you don't care what exception can occur you just want to continue running the program.

Comment: @carlosdumusm: You seem to be understanding this correctly, but I do want to point out that empty `catch` blocks or `catch` blocks that catch all exceptions (i.e., catch the base class `Exception`) are bad, Bad, BAD. You have no idea what type of exception might be thrown but now you are declaring that you can handle all of them. When things are in a bad state, but you don't know how bad or what the bad state is because you are "handling" all exceptions, it is potentially very dangerous to continue as if nothing happened. Handle what you know you can handle, and otherwise fail fast.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense, I have several years programming but I have little knowledge about exceptions, and sometimes don't know where to try-catch or where to throw. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Exceptions are expensive - if you can test and avoid the exception, do so.

Exceptions should not be used for normal program flow.

Answer (score 3):

of course avoid exception,try catch leads to a loss performance.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. 
I almost always try to avoid the exception unless doing so is prohibitively costly.

Answer (score 1):

Purely from a number of instructions / performance standpoint over a significant N runtime, avoiding is more expensive, because you're checking the length every time for every input. With an exception, the `catch` branch is only executed on that eventuality.

Comment: But it's SLOWER when it does happen.  It masks other potential errors.  And it's horrible programming practice.

Comment: The Try-Catch incurs no overhead at all in normal flow? A test and jump as used in the example seems pretty cheap in terms of procesing time.

Comment: It's horrible programming practice when it's an empty `catch {}` that, as you said, masks other programming errors. And as mentioned, exceptions should be used for exceptional conditions, not something that happens routinely (e.g. if you know that the list will always be null on initialization and expect to hit that frequently, it's no longer that exceptional and you should build in a check for it).

Answer (score 0):

Throwing exceptions is an expensive task, so I would always try and validate rather than catch.

This should be easy enough to test, generate some code that throws an exception through each run and test it against a similar set of code that does conditional checking and measure the performance.

If the code is documented with details of which conditions exceptions will be thrown, you should be able to adapt your calling code.  Of course you can't handle every scenario (lower level runtime errors perhaps?), so your code should only really try and handle exceptions where it can actually react and possibly continue.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions should only be used for exceptional conditions (unless there's no alternative), so you should only use try/catch when there's something highly unusual going on that you still need to deal with (pop up an error message).

Having a try/catch also signals to a programmer that some external error might happen and needs to be dealt with. In your example, `list` being null is simply a normal part of program execution/control flow, and so there's nothing exceptional about it.

Also, an empty catch-all is generally a bad thing to have anyway (although there are limited situations where it's needed). It should certainly need a comment anyway to explain why you're not doing anything about the exceptions.

There's a [useful blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) about vexing exception you might find useful

Answer (score -1):

ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS avoid an exception if you can.

Exceptions should be exceptional.

If you can predict it, protect against it happening.

People who use empty catch blocks like that should be banned from using a computer...

It's also faster to not go into catch blocks.