# parse generic type to other generic type

Tags: c#

I created a custom dictionary that takes `Type` as key and an interface as a value. I want to identify the interfaces by their type and there should only exist one of them in that collection. I achieved this by creating this code

```
internal class ComponentCollection
{
    public ComponentCollection()
    {
        components = new Dictionary<Type, IComponent>();
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, IComponent> components;

    public void AddComponent<T>(T component) where T : IComponent
    {
        components.Add(typeof(T), component as IComponent);
    }

    public void RemoveComponent(Type componentType)
    {
        components.Remove(componentType);
    }

    public bool TryGetComponent<T>(out T component)
    {
        try
        {
            component = (T)components[typeof(T)];
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            component = default(T);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and I noticed I can use it for other code places too. I need to replace `IComponent` with a generic type. I started with this

```
internal class TypeCollection<V>
{
    public TypeCollection()
    {
        items = new Dictionary<Type, V>();
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, V> items;

    public void Add<T>(T value) where T : V
    {
        items.Add(typeof(T), value as V);
    }

    public void Remove(Type type)
    {
        items.Remove(type);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue<T>(out T value)
    {
        try
        {
            value = (T)items[typeof(T)];
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but two problems come up.

1. `items.Add(typeof(T), value as V);` crashes because

> The type parameter cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it
>   does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint

2. `value = (T)items[typeof(T)];` crashes because

> Cannot convert type to 'T'

Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the constraint `where T : V` on `Add` you don't need to use `as`.

```
public void Add<T>(T value) where T : V
{
    items.Add(typeof(T), value);
}
```

And this also hints at what you need to do to `TryGetValue`; add a constraint:

```
public bool TryGetValue<T>(out T value) where T : V
{
    try
    {
        value = (T)items[typeof(T)];
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note also that you can implement `TryGetValue` without a try catch, using:

```
public bool TryGetValue<T>(out T value) where T : V
{
    if (items.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var foundValue))
    {
        value = (T)foundValue;
        return true;
    }

    value = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

Or even more succinctly (but arguably less readable):

```
public bool TryGetValue<T>(out T value) where T : V
{
    var found = items.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var foundValue);
    value = found ? (T)foundValue : default(T);
    return found;
}
```

Comment: is your second solution better than using try catch? is `items.TryGetValue` faster than using a try catch block?

Comment: @Question3r Yes, exception handling is expensive, so it's generally recommended to avoid using try/catch blocks for control flow. Some relevant discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628373/1715579) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/107723/81884)

Answer (score 2):

If you are absolutely, positively sure that the thing you're getting really is a `T`, then you can cast from any type to a generic type parameter via:

```
T t = (T)(object)whatever;
```

*However*, if `T` is a value type then this introduces a boxing penalty, which can cause both space and time performance issues. **Track your performance carefully to see if there is a measurable, meaningful impact on this code path**.

And as always, when unboxing you must make sure that the types match exactly. You cannot for example unbox a boxed integer to double, even though you can convert an unboxed integer to double.